# Zend Framework - How to set up auto loader for custom decorators

Tags: zend-framework

I have placed my custom decorators in windows

> application/modules/Tab/forms/decorators

My application works well on windows, but in linux zend cannot found my code in **Zend/Forms/Decorators.** (upper case F and D)

How can I set up auto loader for zend auto load my decorator?
(My custom decorator's name is Tab_Forms_Decorators_Hr)

Comment: `Zend/Form/Decorator` (note singular `Form`)? Don't know why the plural would work in Windows, though... Still, if you are defining custom resource autoloaders, then anything is possible.

Comment: @DavidWeinraub excuse me, but how can I defineing custom resource autoloaders for this?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to confuse you. Not (necessarily) saying you should. Just noting that my suggestions (singular `Form` for the class name) might not apply if you had custom resource autoloaders in place. Since it sounds like you do not, the answer by @Ondrej seems to be on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since default path segment is Form/Decorator and class prefix segment is Form_Decorator (see Zend/Form.php source, `getPluginLoader()` method ), the plural form is weird and the singular one should by used. The `Forms` directory may be used for storing your own Forms models, so maybe some mis-configuration? You didn't post the whole error...

But this don't solve your problem. Try using `addPrefixPath()` to add your own path and prefix, like this (and adjust directories and classes names according to this):

```
$form->addPrefixPath('Tab_Form_Decorator', 'Tab/Form/Decorator', 'decorator');
```

Note the path must begin in some place previously defined (in eg. _initAutoload() Bootstrap.php).